# Reactjs: remove array element, element states don't follow

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

Not sure how to word this question properly in the title.

Scenario:
React app displays an array of 3 Elements (dropdowns), closed by default.

```
I open the second dropdown:
0: state.isOpen: closed
1: state.isOpen: open
2: state.isOpen: closed

I remove the FIRST element of the array:
0: state.isOpen: closed
1: state.isOpen: open
```

Weird, because i expect the the new first element to be open and the second to be closed.  It appears the states don't follow the elements (eg. second element state will go to the new second elemenet state after removal).  I tried not mutating the array, but instead creating a new one and using that to setstate, but same result.

I expect the new [0] to be open and [1] to be closed.  How do i do that?  Thanks.

```
//Accounts.js:
accounts.map( () => { return <Account/>})
removeAccount = () => {
    let accounts = this.state.accounts.map(item => return item)
    accounts.splice...
    this.setState({accounts: accounts})
}

//Account.js:
state.isOpen
removeAccount = this.props.removeAccount
```

Comment: Fixed it.  The reason was because i used the index as the unique key for each element.  Using something else (eg. unique name) for the key resolved this issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your are not cloning your array properly:

```
removeAccount = () => {
    let accounts = [...this.state.accounts]; // Cloning first
    accounts = accounts.map(item => return item) // Do your mappings here
    accounts.splice... // Do your modifications here
    this.setState({accounts: accounts}); // Set the new state 
}
```

Comment: sorry i corrected my code.  I did accounts = state.accounts.map... and then edited the accounts.  And i still get the same bizarre behavior

Comment: map does not clone the array, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to `return` a brand new `array` that excludes your `first` `element` without touching anything else.

See below for a practical example.

```
removeAccount = () => {
  return this.setState((state) => {accounts: [...state.accounts.slice(1)]})
}
```

Comment: Tried it, does not fix the issue.  I already confirmed that using a brand new array will not resolve it.